# How to compare date in template Angular 4

Tags: angular

How to compare array object date value from today ? I searched and tried in many ways but did not find a solution yet.

I have done so far as bellow:

```
*ngIf="patientPrescriptions.appointments_patient_updated_at > now"
```

Comment: the above should work, what is the issue

Comment: Add values that your're trying to compare

Comment: The value : 2017-12-02 16:30:00

Comment: If they're date object then it should work, `date1 = new Date()` and `date2 = new Date()`

Comment: What are the format of  values of  `patientPrescriptions.appointments_patient_updated_at` and `now`. It should be a Date Object which you can achieve as `new Date(patientPrescriptions.appointments_patient_updated_at)` and similarly for now `new Date(now)` and then compare  these two values

Comment: This *ngIf=new Date(patientPrescriptions.appointments_patient_updated_at) > new Date(now) does not work ether.

Comment: If *ngIf="2 > 1" works then  why *ngIf=new Date(2017-12-03 16:30:00) > new Date(2017-12-02 16:30:00) does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have solved it like this:

In typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.now = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:s');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution and it works for me,
In your ts file

```
const now = new Date;
today: string ;
this.today =now.toISOString();
```

And in your html file,

```
 *ngIf= "model.LeaveFrom > today"
```

It gives you date if model date is greater than today.